# 100 Connections Limit in Realtime Database for 1 minute/1hour/1day?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I added `Realtime Database` and write data once. Now in Usage it shows **1/100 connection** after **one app install.** (after app close it still showing 1 connection).

> If my small app has 300 downloads per day it means 300 connections per day. 101st user not able to `read/write` data.

I explore many questions, but no one give details about this confusion. I want to use `Firebase` `free` for this small app.
**What time limit for 100 connections? This limit for one day  or 1 Hour or 1 Minute??**

.
[image: Firebase Realtime database]

Answer (score 1):

> On Android, Firebase automatically manages connection state to reduce
> bandwidth and battery usage. When a client has no active listeners, no
> pending write or onDisconnect operations, and is not explicitly
> disconnected by the goOffline method, Firebase closes the connection
> after 60 seconds of inactivity.

I couldn't find the iOS documentation, but it should also have a default inactivity period of 60 seconds.

With a low number of concurrent users, you shouldn't reach the connection limit.

You can also explicitly disconnect on app close

```swift
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        Database.database().goOnline()
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        Database.database().goOffline()
    }
```

reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state

Comment: still confuse. Is there any time limit for 100 connections?